# How to prevent scrolling in UIScrollView when action is performed

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using https://github.com/PaoloCuscela/Cards inside of a UIScrollView. When the card is opened, it's impossible to close because the whole view scrolls. Is there a way to disable scrolling while the card is opened and reenable when it's closed?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619395-isscrollenabled

Comment: set scrollview content size to (0,0)

Comment: I'm adding the code to the Cards pod, but I can't access my UIScrollView from there.

Comment: if its implemented somewhere inside the cards library then obviously you wouldnt be able to access it due to data hiding(abstraction), so you might have to dig in a little deep and then customise the classes as per your requirements.  EDIT: i checked the source code seems like uicollectionview is being used instead of scrollview